# Create a toggle out of a UIButton not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, button, toggle

everyone!

So basically, I am trying to create a simple toggle out of my UIButton. With the code below, I am able to click the button, but only for a brief moment do I see @"Expense" as the title. It is probably a VERY simple mistake. Any help is appreciated!

```
- (IBAction)typeChanger {
if ([typeButton.titleLabel.text isEqual:@"Income"]) {
    typeButton.titleLabel.text = @"Expense";
}else if ([typeButton.titleLabel.text isEqual:@"Expense"]) {
    typeButton.titleLabel.text = @"Income";
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if ([typeButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Income"]) write this in condition...

Comment: Oh, okay. Didn't know that! But the same problem occurs.

Comment: hey guys, `[typeButton.titleLabel.text isEqual:@"Income"]` is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use NSString's `isEqualToString:` method instead of `isEqual` for string comparisons (either should work, but it's faster according to the docs).

Also, you need to use `setTitle:forState:` to set the title of a `UIButton`... the two important states to set are `UIControlStateNormal` (not pressed) and `UIControlStateHighlighted` (for when it's pressed):

```
- (IBAction)typeChanger {
    if ([[typeButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:@"Income"]) {
         [typeButton setTitle:@"Expense" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [typeButton setTitle:@"Expense" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    } else if ([[typeButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:@"Expense"]) {
         [typeButton setTitle:@"Income" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [typeButton setTitle:@"Income" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
}
```

See also the docs on `NSString`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

And on `UIButton`:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Comment: Oh, okay. Didn't know that! But the same problem occurs.

Comment: You have to use `UIButton`'s `setTitle:forState:` method to set the title state. While there are several states, `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateHighlighted` are most commonly set and most important.

Comment: Okay, I see. It works, thanks again! Couple questions, though. UIControlStateHighlighted is  when the button is being pressed? Also, when I want to compare the values, like if the title is equal to something, then how would that be done?

Comment: Would it be like if (typebutton.titleLabel.text == @"Income")?

Comment: Yeah, it's actually better to also use `UIButton`'s `titleForState:` method to query what the title for a given state is. See revised answer again.

Answer (score 2):

Do like this,

```
- (IBAction)typeChanger {
if ([typeButton.titleLabel.text isEqual:@"Income"]) {
   [typeButton setTitle:@"Expense" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else if ([typeButton.titleLabel.text isEqual:@"Expense"]) {
    [typeButton setTitle:@"Income" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

Comment: I don't like this because (1) you're ignoring the pressed state (so visual disparities- different text when pressed- are possible) and (2) `typeButton.titleLabel` is supposed to be `primarily to configure the button` according to the docs... not for setting or querying the button's title values (as that's what `setTitle:forState` and `titleForState:` respectively are meant for).

Answer (score 2):

This may be very useful and handy. Try this out.

https://github.com/Brayden/UICheckbox